# Skip writing to dateframe when table values are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following `df`:

```
    Invoicenumber    Invoicedate
--  ---------------  --------------
 0  860132298L01     NaN
 2  78825701         NaN
 6  78835257         NaN
13  NaN              NaN
21  NaN              2021-03-16
```

I **don't** want to write the `NaN` values to the columns of a `df`:

What I get now with the following code:

```
df4 = ({
'Factuurnummer':"""
  <cbc:ID>"""+dfresult['Factuurnummer'] +"""</cbc:ID>""",
'Factuurdatum':"""
  <cbc:IssueDate>""" + dfresult['Factuurdatum'].astype(str) + """</cbc:IssueDate>""",
})
Invoicenumber                   Invoicedate
-----------------------------  -----------------------------------------
<cbc:ID>860132298L01</cbc:ID>  <cbc:IssueDate>NaN</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:ID>78825701</cbc:ID>      <cbc:IssueDate>NaN</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:ID>78835257</cbc:ID>      <cbc:IssueDate>NaN</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:ID>NaN</cbc:ID>           <cbc:IssueDate>NaN</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:ID>NaN</cbc:ID>           <cbc:IssueDate>2021-03-16</cbc:IssueDate>
```

The `NaN` values are `np.64` data type..

However, I want the line to not appear in the `df` when the value is `NaN`.

Desired output:

```
Invoicenumber                  Invoicedate
-----------------------------  -----------------------------------------
<cbc:ID>860132298L01</cbc:ID>  
<cbc:ID>78825701</cbc:ID>      
<cbc:ID>78835257</cbc:ID>      
         
                              <cbc:IssueDate>2021-03-16</cbc:IssueDate>
```

Please help!

Comment: `df4.fillna('')`

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fillna

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @piRSquared however getting above error..

Comment: @piRSquared asked you to apply `fillna('')` on a dataframe, not on a dictionary

Comment: This does not remove the entire line unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which applies a function to every element of a DataFrame.

```py
df4 = df4.applymap(lambda x: '' if 'NaN' in str(x) else x)
```